# Why JSON not deserialized to NameValueCollection

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I have JSON object on client side like following:

```
    var myObject = {
      data1: 1,
      data2: 5,
      .......
    }
```

I am passing it to `PageMethod` and expecting that it will be deserialized as `Dictionary<string, object>`. It is working right. But when I replacing `Dictionary` in PageMethod signature with `NameValueCollection` deserialization failed. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Because the JavaScriptSerializer that is used by page methods is not able to deserialize this JSON structure to a weakly typed NameValueCollection. Why would you want to do that instead of working with a strongly typed dictionary anyway?

Comment: For my purposes `null` as empty value is enough/preferred. I trying to write compact code and when I using Dictionary I need firstly check whether dictionary contains key.

Answer (score 1):

NameValueCollection cannot be serialized like Dictionary because it does not implement IDictionary.

You can convert it to a dictionary and then try serializing.

Comment: Okay, it is not implements IDictionary... so what?

Comment: so javascriptserializer cannot serialize it

Answer (score 0):

You can try "mapping". In code you can use property Coll as NameValueCollection, but serialization/deserialization works with CollDictionary.

```
public NameValueCollection Coll
{
    get
    {
        var nvc = new NameValueCollection();
        CollDictionary.Keys.ToList().ForEach(a => nvc.Add(a, CollDictionary[a]));
        return nvc;
    }
    set
    {
        CollDictionary = value.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => value[k]);
    }
}

[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Coll")]
public Dictionary<string, string> CollDictionary { get; set; }
```